# Storage symlink doesn't work with Laravel and Vue in Namecheap CPanel (LiteSpeed)

Tags: laravel, deployment, cpanel, namecheap, litespeed

I am trying to access my image files stored inside `storage/app/public/subfolder/` using symlink inside `/public` folder in my Laravel app. Everything works fine in my local setup and also in Jelastic Apache deployment, but it doesn't seem to work in CPanel with LiteSpeed. I am trying to access the files using the link `/storage/subfolder/image.png` but it is not accessible on CPanel deployment.

I tried creating and deleting storage symlink hundreds of times, but it didn't work. Below are few things I tried:

1. Deleting and creating symlink again and again using `php artisan storage:link` command.
2. Creating symlink using linux command `ln -s ../storage/app/public storage` inside public folder.
3. Running `Artisan::call('storage:link')` using a web route entry.
4. Redeploying and reconfiguring the app several times and creating storage symlink.

In all of these failed attempts I can verify that storage symlink is created every time inside public folder. I can navigate and view files from `public/storage/` folder using CPanel terminal without any issues but can't access them in the deployed app.

I have exact same configuration in Jelastic Apache deployment and in my local deployment and there it is working without any issues.

**UPDATE:**

Additionally, I tried creating a `storage` directly manually inside `public` folder with the same structure and it worked. But symlink doesn't work.

**UPDATE 2:**
I found below error log while checking error logs from CPanel.

```
2022-11-06 05:07:07.342556 [ERROR] [1669834] [T0] [HTAccess] Failed to open [/home/user/my-project/public/storage/subfolder/.htaccess]: Permission denied
```

There is no `.htaccess` inside `subfolder` but it is there in my public folder.

What might be the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long search, I finally found the cause.

Somehow the `storage/app/public` directory didn't have sufficient permissions. So, I gave permissions to that public folder recursively using `chmod` and everything works fine now.

The symlink was working fine but it was not working due to permission issues in the parent folder.

This is a bit weird as I have never manually altered permissions in any Laravel folders in any of my other deployments.

Answer (score 0):

After making linking you storage to your public path using storage:link you can access your folder :
'Storage_path('subfolder/image.png');'

Comment: Actually I am using it inside my Vue project and there I am using as: `<img src="/storage/subfolder/image.png"/>`. It works fine locally and in my Apache deployment but not working here.

Comment: try <img :src="'../storage/subfolder/image.png'">

Comment: I don't think wrong path is the issue here. I tested it by manually creating a storage directory inside public folder and putting files in there with the same tree as storage/app/public and that is working fine. So the issue is completely related to symlink. When directory is manually created (instead of symlink) files are accessible using the same path as above.